# Polymorph spell

Tags: damage

Wizard polymorphs another party member into a giant ape, both the wizard and the ape are hit by the same attack, dragon breath. Wizard is incapacitated so loses concentration.
Does the ape take the damage as hit at the same time, or does the original player take the damage as the spell was dropped?

Comment: Welcome to the stack Jodpal, take the [tour] when you have moment. It isn’t clear to me what game you are playing, could you edit the question or add the appropriate tag to let us know what game (and edition) this question is about?

Comment: Hi Jodpal, I've made an edit on the assumption that this is D&D 5e. You can view it checking the post's [revision history](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/posts/197464/revisions). If you are playing 5e, simply roll back to that edit and we'll get this re-opened for you. Otherwise you can [edit] the post to add the appropriate system tag.